# (Python, Pandas) - How do I get everything to the left of a certain character?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a column, `market_area` that I want to abbreviate by keeping only the part of the string to the left of the hyphen.

For example, my data is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'market_area': ['San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose',
                                    None, 
                                    'Dallas-Fort Worth', 
                                    'Los Angeles-Riverside-Orange County'],
                    'val': [1,2,3,4]})
```

My desired output would be:

```
['San Francisco', None, 'Dallas', 'Los Angeles']
```

I am able to split based on the hyphen:

```
tmp['market_area'].str.split('-')
```

But how do I extract only the part to the left of the hyphen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the first element in the splitted list using `.str[0]`:

```
tmp.market_area.str.split('-').str[0]
Out[3]:
0    San Francisco
1             None
2           Dallas
3      Los Angeles
Name: market_area, dtype: object
```

Or use `str.extract` method with regex `^([^-]*).*`, which captures the pattern until the first `-`:

```
tmp.market_area.str.extract('^([^-]*).*', expand=False)
Out[5]:
0    San Francisco
1              NaN
2           Dallas
3      Los Angeles
Name: market_area, dtype: object
```